How do I convert a 3D array into a series of 2D arrays in R?
I have a multi-dimensional array, which we can call OccProbs, which has the following structure:
num [1:750, 1:42, 1:8099]

1:750 refers to 750 sampled probabilities of a species presence, 1:42 refers to 42 individual individual species, and 1:8099 refers to 8099 individual pixels of the total study area. dput gives too large of an output to include here even when I do dput(head(OccProbs, 2)), soI include two snippets of the data to illustrate more clearly how it is structured
, , 1
              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]         [,7]       
 [1,] 1.176021e-02 8.906702e-05 1.028353e-04 9.997413e-01 1.986901e-08 7.933022e-01 1.671345e-06 
 [2,] 4.971576e-01 2.815204e-05 1.297598e-06 1.000000e+00 3.940257e-05 9.462796e-01 8.510594e-08
 [3,] 9.999987e-01 1.822639e-07 1.205088e-03 7.722223e-01 1.264299e-06 9.999990e-01 3.338352e-10 
 [4,] 9.640078e-01 6.319505e-06 4.515647e-05 9.994119e-01 1.486193e-05 9.999854e-01 6.594763e-09 
 [5,] 9.734548e-01 1.181870e-10 4.074234e-04 9.999940e-01 1.668805e-04 9.998125e-01 1.237284e-10 


, , 2
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]         [,7]
[1,] 1.000000e+00 5.714264e-08 4.037019e-06 8.570922e-14 8.051091e-06 3.226571e-06 5.742324e-06 
[2,] 1.000000e+00 4.958478e-12 9.438453e-01 3.996803e-15 7.543438e-06 3.548187e-08 2.521668e-03 
[3,] 1.000000e+00 2.068027e-09 7.473084e-06 5.091483e-13 2.178850e-03 1.003287e-05 9.050913e-05 
[4,] 1.000000e+00 1.902034e-08 4.499343e-10 2.305716e-10 1.476408e-01 6.853635e-08 3.187804e-02 
[5,] 1.000000e+00 9.084289e-12 9.629695e-01 3.599236e-08 2.859380e-01 1.944976e-06 1.234365e-01 

This was produced using the spMsPGOcc() and predict() function from the spOccupancy package in R. This array is the $psi.0.samples produced by predict() .
I want to break up this array so that it it provides the average sampled probability of each of the individual species in each pixel. The order of the pixels has to stay the same as the order of the matrices. I suspect that the easiest way to do this is to first get the average of each column in each array, and then split/merge the array, splitting by species and merging so that each column which corresponds to the same species, which are identified by numbers such as [, 1] in this dataset. Ideally I would also want to preserve the sd of the predicted occuapncy of each species in each pixel, but that is not strictly required.
Thus far, I tried to create a dataframe as follows:
plot.dat <- data.frame(x = Coords$Easting, 
                       y = Coords$Northing, 
                       mean.psi = apply(OccProbs, c(1,3), mean), 
                       sd.psi = apply(OccProbs, c(1,3), sd))

But this got the error of:
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8099, 750

However on reflection I realise that even if this had worked, it would not have split the results up by species.
Effectively I would want a way to take a 3D array that looks a bit like this (I have added words as labels to try to make it easier to explain the actual dataset doesn't have labels):
  , , Pixel_1

         [Species_A]     [Species_B]     [Species_C]        
    [1,] 3               5               3 
    [2,] 4               4               8
    [3,] 7               8               2
    
    
    , , Pixel_2

         [Species_A]     [Species_B]     [Species_C]        
    [1,] 5               7               2 
    [2,] 3               4               3
    [3,] 6               9               5
    
    , , Pixel_3
    
         [Species_A]     [Species_B]     [Species_C]        
    [1,] 3               1               6
    [2,] 4               5               1
    [3,] 2               6               2

And turns it into a series of distinct 2D arrays (not a 3D array) which looks something like this:
Species_A
         [mean]     [sd]
[Pixel_1]4.666      1.699
[Pixel_2]4.666      1.247
[Pixel_3]3.000      0.816

Species_B
         [mean]     [sd]
[Pixel_1]5.666      1.699
[Pixel_2]6.666      2.055
[Pixel_3]4.000      2.160

Species_C
         [mean]     [sd]
[Pixel_1]4.333      1.699
[Pixel_2]3.333      1.247
[Pixel_3]3.000      2.160


Maybe you can simplify the question by making a much smaller matrix and demonstrating your desired output.

Thanks for your suggestion! I have added an example using a smaller matrix and the desired output.

How did you get the sd?

I did the small example output manually, I know how to get this sort of result with a 2D array but an unsure how to get it with a 3D array

Use apply + aperm
aperm(apply(ar, -1, \(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))), c(3,1,2))

, , Species_A

             mean       sd
pixels_1 4.666667 2.081666
pixels_2 4.666667 1.527525
pixels_3 3.000000 1.000000

, , Species_B

             mean       sd
pixels_1 5.666667 2.081666
pixels_2 6.666667 2.516611
pixels_3 4.000000 2.645751

, , Species_C

             mean       sd
pixels_1 4.333333 3.214550
pixels_2 3.333333 1.527525
pixels_3 3.000000 2.645751


Data:
ar <- structure(c(3L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 
4L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L), dim = c(3L, 
3L, 3L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("Species_A", "Species_B", "Species_C"
), c("pixels_1", "pixels_2", "pixels_3")))


If this refers to how to make data frames from array slices,
> (A <- array(1:12, c(3, 2, 2)))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]    8   11
[3,]    9   12

> dim(A)
[1] 3 2 2

you can do
> (res <- lapply(seq_len(dim(A)[3]), \(i) A[,,i]))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]    8   11
[3,]    9   12

where
> lapply(res, dim) |> lengths()
[1] 2 2


isnt this simply asplit(A, 3)? I do not knwo what OP wants since the results seem to be a 3d array still. Unless OP needs a list
